# Laravel 5 Captcha in Laravel 5 is not visible

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I use Laravel 5.1 and this captcha package: https://github.com/mewebstudio/captcha.

When using this: {{Captcha::img()}} in my blade.php it doesn't show me the captch image. It just prints me out the following html:

```
<img src="http://localhost/myproject/public/captcha/default?xyD4gHW2" alt="captcha">
```

Any ideas why? Thank you

Answer (score 3):

do this:

```
{!! Captcha::img() !!}}
```

from the docs:
https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/blade

> By default, Blade {{ }} statements are automatically sent through
>   PHP's htmlentities function to prevent XSS attacks. If you do not want
>   your data to be escaped, you may use the following syntax:
>
> Hello, {!! $name !!}. Note: Be very careful when echoing content that
>   is supplied by users of your application. Always use the double curly
>   brace syntax to escape any HTML entities in the content.